# How to use nhibernate with ASP.NET 3.5 (not MVC)

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, crud

What is the best way to interop with NHibernate 2.0 and ASP.NET 3.5? How can I easily develop a CRUD application?

Is the ObjectDataSource the way to go?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find [Rhino Commons](http://ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Commons.ashx) a good option.  It offers Repository<T> and UnitOfWorkApplication.  Together these provide data gateway and session management in the context of a web application.  Use with [Castle.Service.Transaction](http://www.jroller.com/hammett/entry/the_joys_of_castle_services) to handle transactions transparently.

Answer (score 3):

you can watch screencasts at
http://www.summerofnhibernate.com/
that will explain how to set up CRUD, and will shed some light on more advanced topics